# Записать синхронно всё, что мы видим на мониторе и слышим из динамиков (как вариант из наушников), без микрофона

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Задача записать синхронно всё, что мы видим на мониторе и слышим из динамиков (как вариант из наушников), без микрофона.

Я написал следующий скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Задаём переменную:
speaker=alsa_output.pci-[мои динамики].analog-stereo.monitor
 
#Пишем: 
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f pulse -i $speaker \ 
   -f x11grab -s 1200x900 -r 15 -i :0.0 -vcodec qtrle screencast2.mov
```

Проблема в том, что звук записывается с задержкой, а мне разумеется надо синхронно.

В чём причина? Что исправить?

Comment: OBS попробуйте, может, лучше будет

Comment: Мне в командной строке линукс надо.

Comment: OBS так тоже умеет

Comment: Сколько помню, у ffmpeg всегда были проблемы с синхронизацией звука, лучше действительно попробовать поискать более специализированный софт

Comment: Выставите компенсацию задержки.